# How to remove a key value pair from mongodb when updating findOne result?

Tags: mongoose

```
user.findOne(params,(err,user){   
    if(user){  
        user.password=password;
        delete user['otp'];
        user.save(callback);
    }
})
```

my user model has following fields

1. user_id:string
2. otp:number
3. password:string

I want to remove `otp` field on update of `password`
ie. db should have `userid` and `password` after update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the `otp` key from your document, setting the path to `undefined` and saving it should do it:

```
user.findOne(params, (err, user){
  if (user) {
    user.password = password;
    user.otp = undefined;
    user.save(callback);
  }
});
```

Comment: that was just an example.

Comment: @MadhveshS No worries then! Understood, I'll edit my answer.